# How to Update the Contents of an "enum Flag" Instance using an Internal Class Method?

Tags: python, flags

Good evening fellow coders,

I'm currently working on a python-based project that uses flags, for which I use the `Flag` class from the `enum` library.

What I am struggling to do, is update the contents of an instance value, purely with the use of an internal class method. To better explain, please refer to the following *simplified* class example:

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class MyFlags(Flag):
  Null = auto()
  A = auto()
  B = auto()
  C = auto()
  D = auto()

  @classmethod
  @property
  def Class(cls):
    return cls

  def get_flag_list(self):
    """create a list of flags contained within the instance"""
    _outputList = []
    for flag in self.Class:
      if flag in self:
        _outputList.append(flag)
    return _outputList

  def update(self, givenFlags):
    """EXAMPLE: update instance contents using the contents of the passed variable"""
    if not isinstance(givenFlags, self.Class):
      raise TypeError(f"\"update\" method requires a class of type {self.Class}!")
    _compare = givenFlags.get_flag_list()
    print(f"--- flags before: {self}")  # print check before
    for flag in _compare:
      if flag not in self:
        self ^= flag                    # bit-wise xor command to add flag
    print(f"--- flags after: {self}")   # print check after
```

Using this class, I instantiate two flag variables:

```
x = MyFlags.A | MyFlags.B
y = MyFlags.B | MyFlags.C | MyFlags.D
```

I then try to update the contents of the instance `x` through the use of its internal `update` method, and print its contents both before and after the `update` call:

```
print(x)
x.update(y)  # also prints the before/after contents of the instance
print(x)
```

What I expect, is for the `update` method to work like the `update` method used with the pythonic `set` type, in which the method has no return value, yet still updates the contents of the calling instance. Instead, the aforementioned code results in the following output:

> MyFlags.B|A
>
> --- flags before: MyFlags.B|A
>
> --- flags after: MyFlags.D|C|B|A
>
> MyFlags.B|A

As seen above, the `self` call of the instance was correctly updated *within* the method, yet the changes were discarded after the method finished its execution.

I know it is possible to `return self` from the `update` method, and reassign the instance of `x`, as follows:

```
x = x.update(y)
```

If at all possible, I would like to avoid a return value for this method.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

R.Fox

Comment: because nowhere in the method do you mutate the instance. Indeed, I think enum instances are meant to be immutable. That is one of their core features. So maybe just don't use an enum?

Comment: so, suppose I define a function, `def foo(self): self += 1` then I do `x = 0; foo(x); print(x)`, obviously, `x` will still be `0`. this is essentially exactly what is happening in your `update` method

Comment: btw, the `Class` method is pretty pointless. just use `type(x)` instead of `x.Class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @*juanpa.arrivillaga* in the comments for pointing me in the right direction!

> **juanpa.arrivillaga, June 20, 8:57**
>
> *... nowhere in the method do you mutate the instance... enum instances are meant to be immutable. That is one of their core features...*

As the `Enum` and `Flag` classes are immutable, my attempt at reassigning the instance's value from *within* the instance was the wrong approach. Having refreshed my memory on mutable an immutable objects through the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), I believe I only have 3 courses of action:

1. make use of the `return` value of the method to replace the old variable with a completely new instance
2. attempt to change the attributes of the base class and make it mutable
3. create a self-defined `Flag` class with the functionality I need (*which might be a fun exercise!*)